# Apache Nifi Historical Statistics of a Component

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

Can anbody explain this min/max/mean in the following screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It shows the Minimal, Maximal and Mean number of output files per some predetermined amount of time (my guess a minute in your case).

"
**Min/Max/Mean**: The minimum, maximum, and mean (arithmetic mean, or average) values are shown. These values are based only on the range of time selected, if any time range is selected. If this instance of NiFi is clustered, these values are shown for the cluster as a whole, as well as each individual node. In a clustered environment, each node is shown in a different color. This also serves as the graph's legend, showing the color of each node that is shown in the graph. Hovering the mouse over the Cluster or one of the nodes in the legend will also make the corresponding node bold in the graph."

You can read more about it in the official documentation:

[User Guide - Historical Statistics of a Component](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDF3/HDF-3.1.2/bk_user-guide/content/Status_History.html)

Comment: I have read it already but it is not clear . Min value is minimum number of output files per minute . can you clarify it a little more as output value of min will be very high 29137 record per minute.

Comment: The time duration for this stat is _5 minutes_ (seen in the dropdown in the top right corner).

Comment: I have  selected a small portion out of the graph and time duration is less than 5 minutes